# 2013 Online - Can you turn off external sharing on subsite level?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I know it's possible to turn off external sharing for a site collection but was wondering if it was possible to turn it off on site and subsite level? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are settings at site level to set these option. I haven`t tested but as per documentation you can follow the steps.

- Site Settings
- Site Permissions
- Access Request Settings
- Uncheck "Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders." option.
- Save changes.

Here is an article 
http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2014/11/managing-sharing-access-requests-sharepoint-site/

Try, it might work.